# Batch error not letting me set a variable

Tags: batch-file

I'm making a shell based off batch and powershell (mainly batch though).

I have a little snip-it of code:

```
:prompt
@echo off
title JDOS command line
echo.
echo.
SET /P command=%FDIR%>
```

But whenever I add the `>` in the code, it quits with a message: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

So, is there any possible way to bypass this in order for the > display?

BTW: I would love it if you helped me in this; so far I am alone.  http://1drv.ms/1VT7grx

Feel free to edit the link ^ above ^ and add whatever you feel like, help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways

1) `SET /P command=%FDIR%^>` as in the shawnt00 comment

2) `SET /P "command=%FDIR%>"` which in some cases can be safer

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the caret (`^`) to escape the redirection character (`>`) as a literal.